# Broken pipe when implementing Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot MVC application that was working fine.

I'm trying to follow a number of tutorials on integrating Spring Security to handle user login, however as soon as I create the following class, the application starts generating a Broken pipe error.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

I've tried a number of different tutorials thinking that maybe the original tutorial had some errors, but it's still happening.

```
2015-11-25 09:39:57.593  INFO 64614 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-11-25 09:39:57.620  INFO 64614 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 27 ms
2015-11-25 09:39:58.970 ERROR 64614 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/login] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

I can't figure out what's causing this.

I'm deploying this application on a local Tomcat instance.

To confirm, the application still appears to be working ok, I'm not sure if this error is something I need to worry about?

Comment: A few more lines of the stack trace would help - at least to see the _Spring_ code being invoked

Comment: It looks like it was an issue with my code. I had @RequestMapping("/") which was redirecting to another method, and was somehow causing an error with security.

Comment: It seems this is still an issue, I've updated the original question to expand on the error I get.

Comment: My comment still stands. We need to see where the code causing the exception is invoked from, possibly from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, but I think this kind of error can depend of lot of things. Me too I use spring-boot with angularJs stack.

I have the same issue when I try to wait the answer of the request (who take time) to my spring-boot application.

I put **my solution** here if it's can help someone:

For me, the problem come from **Apache Httpd** configuration, because I put my application behind apache server. And in my case, apache close the connexion when it's exceed the default timeout (300 seconds I think). When this happens your spring-boot display `broken pipe` error.

To fix this problem you just need to add `TimeOut yourValueInSecond` in the `httpd.conf` of your apache httpd configuration file.

Before to change your configuration file test if it's really due to the apache httpd server by sending the request directly on your tomcat server.